# Error: Element value must be a constant expression

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to merge 2 android studio projects into one.
Here's my app level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cricketbuzz"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.cricketbuzzsdk:CricketBuzzSDK:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    compile project(':basketball')

}
```

Here's my library build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
      //  applicationId "com.gmail.jorgegilcavazos.ballislife"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 3
        versionName "0.1.0"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENCE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.3.0'
    compile 'net.dean.jraw:JRAW:0.9.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
}
```

The error I am getting is :

C:\Users\karanc\AndroidStudioProjects\CricketBuzz\basketball\src\main\java\com\gmail\jorgegilcavazos\ballislife\features\games\GameAdapter.java
Error:(112, 23) error: element value must be a constant expression

C:\Users\karanc\AndroidStudioProjects\CricketBuzz\basketball\src\main\java\com\gmail\jorgegilcavazos\ballislife\features\gamethread\CommentThreadFragment.java
Error:(127, 22) error: constant expression required

Here are GameAdapter & CommentThread files:
GameAdapter.java

```
    package com.gmail.jorgegilcavazos.ballislife.features.games;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.gmail.jorgegilcavazos.ballislife.features.data.NbaGame;
import com.gmail.jorgegilcavazos.ballislife.R;
import com.gmail.jorgegilcavazos.ballislife.util.Utilities;

import java.util.List;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

import static android.support.design.R.styleable.RecyclerView;

/**
 * RecyclerView Adapter used by the {@link GamesFragment} to display a list of games.
 */
public class GameAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GameAdapter.GameViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<NbaGame> nbaGameList;
    private GamesFragment.GameItemListener gameItemListener;



    public GameAdapter(List<NbaGame> nbaGames,
                       GamesFragment.GameItemListener itemListener) {
        nbaGameList = nbaGames;
        gameItemListener = itemListener;
    }

    @Override
    public GameViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_game,
                parent, false);
        context = parent.getContext();
        return new GameViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final GameViewHolder holder, int position) {
        NbaGame nbaGame = nbaGameList.get(position);

        int resKeyHome = context.getResources().getIdentifier(nbaGame.getHomeTeamAbbr()
                .toLowerCase(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        int resKeyAway = context.getResources().getIdentifier(nbaGame.getAwayTeamAbbr()
                .toLowerCase(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());

        holder.tvHomeTeam.setText(nbaGame.getHomeTeamAbbr());
        holder.tvAwayTeam.setText(nbaGame.getAwayTeamAbbr());
        holder.ivHomeLogo.setImageResource(resKeyHome);
        holder.ivAwayLogo.setImageResource(resKeyAway);
        holder.tvHomeScore.setText(nbaGame.getHomeTeamScore());
        holder.tvAwayScore.setText(nbaGame.getAwayTeamScore());
        holder.tvClock.setText(nbaGame.getGameClock());
        holder.tvPeriod.setText(Utilities.getPeriodString(nbaGame.getPeriodValue(),
                nbaGame.getPeriodName()));

        holder.tvHomeScore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.tvAwayScore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.tvClock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.tvPeriod.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.tvFinal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.tvTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        switch (nbaGame.getGameStatus()) {
            case NbaGame.PRE_GAME:
                holder.tvTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.tvTime.setText(nbaGame.getPeriodStatus());
                break;
            case NbaGame.IN_GAME:
                holder.tvHomeScore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.tvAwayScore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.tvClock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.tvPeriod.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case NbaGame.POST_GAME:
                holder.tvHomeScore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.tvAwayScore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.tvFinal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.tvFinal.setText("FINAL");
                break;
        }

        holder.container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                gameItemListener.onGameClick(nbaGameList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return null != nbaGameList ? nbaGameList.size() : 0;
    }

    public void swap(List<NbaGame> data) {
        nbaGameList.clear();
        nbaGameList.addAll(data);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static class GameViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View container;
        @BindView(R.id.homelabel) TextView tvHomeTeam;
        @BindView(R.id.awaylabel) TextView tvAwayTeam;
        @BindView(R.id.homescore) TextView tvHomeScore;
        @BindView(R.id.awayscore) TextView tvAwayScore;
        @BindView(R.id.clock) TextView tvClock;
        @BindView(R.id.period) TextView tvPeriod;
        @BindView(R.id.extraLabel) TextView tvTime;
        @BindView(R.id.extraLabel2) TextView tvFinal;
        @BindView(R.id.homeicon) ImageView ivHomeLogo;
        @BindView(R.id.awayicon) ImageView ivAwayLogo;

        public GameViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
            container = view;
        }
    }
}
```

CommentThread.java

```
package com.gmail.jorgegilcavazos.ballislife.features.gamethread;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.gmail.jorgegilcavazos.ballislife.features.shared.CommentAdapter;
import com.gmail.jorgegilcavazos.ballislife.R;
import com.gmail.jorgegilcavazos.ballislife.util.AuthListener;
import com.gmail.jorgegilcavazos.ballislife.util.MyDebug;
import com.gmail.jorgegilcavazos.ballislife.network.RedditAuthentication;
import com.gmail.jorgegilcavazos.ballislife.util.RedditUtils;

import net.dean.jraw.http.SubmissionRequest;
import net.dean.jraw.models.CommentNode;
import net.dean.jraw.models.CommentSort;
import net.dean.jraw.models.Listing;
import net.dean.jraw.models.Submission;
import net.dean.jraw.paginators.Sorting;
import net.dean.jraw.paginators.SubredditPaginator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CommentThreadFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "CommentThreadFragment";

    public interface SubmissionListingFetchListener {
        void onSuccess(Listing<Submission> submissions);
        void onFailure(String message);
    }

    public interface FullSubmissionFetchListener {
        void onSuccess(Submission submission);
        void onFailure(String message);
    }

    public static final String HOME_TEAM_KEY = "HOME_TEAM";
    public static final String AWAY_TEAM_KEY = "AWAY_TEAM";
    public static final String THREAD_TYPE_KEY = "THREAD_TYPE";
    private static final String NBA_SUBREDDIT = "nba";
    private static final int SEARCH_LIMIT = 100;

    private static final int RETRY_FIND_SUBMISSION = 0;
    private static final int RETRY_FETCH_COMMENTS = 1;

    private String mHomeTeam;
    private String mAwayTeam;
    private String mThreadId;
    private boolean mFoundThreadId;
    private RedditUtils.GameThreadType mThreadType;

    Context mContext;

    View rootView;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    CommentAdapter mCommentAdapter;
    ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    Snackbar mSnackbar;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mHomeTeam = getArguments().getString(HOME_TEAM_KEY);
            mAwayTeam = getArguments().getString(AWAY_TEAM_KEY);
            mThreadType = (RedditUtils.GameThreadType) getArguments().get(THREAD_TYPE_KEY);
        }
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_comment_thread, container, false);

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.comment_thread_rv);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        } else {
            ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(mRecyclerView, false);
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = getActivity();

        if (mFoundThreadId) {
            fetchComments();
        } else {
            findGameSubmission();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        dismissSnackbar();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_refresh:
                dismissSnackbar();
                if (mFoundThreadId) {
                    fetchComments();
                } else {
                    findGameSubmission();
                }
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Starts a {@link FetchSubmissionListing} task that retrieves a list of submissions in the
     * /r/nba subreddit. If it is successfully retrieved, it tries to find the one that belongs
     * to this game and shows its comment tree.
     */
    private void findGameSubmission() {
        AuthListener authListener = new AuthListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                findGameSubmission();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure() {
                showSnackBar("Failed to connect to Reddit", true, RETRY_FIND_SUBMISSION);
            }
        };
        SubmissionListingFetchListener fetchListener =  new SubmissionListingFetchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Listing<Submission> submissions) {
                mThreadId = RedditUtils.findNbaGameThreadId(submissions, mThreadType,
                        mHomeTeam, mAwayTeam);
                if (mThreadId != null) {
                    mFoundThreadId = true;
                    fetchComments();
                } else {
                    mFoundThreadId = false;
                    showSnackBar("No comment thread found", true, RETRY_FIND_SUBMISSION);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                showSnackBar(message, true, RETRY_FIND_SUBMISSION);
            }
        };
        new FetchSubmissionListing(mContext, NBA_SUBREDDIT, SEARCH_LIMIT, Sorting.NEW,
                fetchListener, authListener).execute();
    }

    /**
     * Starts a {@link FetchFullSubmission} task that retrieves the Submission of the given
     * submissionId. A "full" submissions is one that also contains its comment tree.
     */
    private void fetchComments() {
        AuthListener authListener = new AuthListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                fetchComments();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure() {
                showSnackBar("Failed to connect to Reddit", true, RETRY_FETCH_COMMENTS);
            }
        };

        FullSubmissionFetchListener fetchListener = new FullSubmissionFetchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Submission submission) {
                loadComments(submission);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                showSnackBar(message, true, RETRY_FIND_SUBMISSION);
            }
        };
        new FetchFullSubmission(mContext, mThreadId, fetchListener, authListener).execute();
    }

    /**
     * Loads a tree of comments into the RecyclerView, given a Reddit Submission.
     */
    private void loadComments(Submission submission) {
        Iterable<CommentNode> iterable = submission.getComments().walkTree();
        List<CommentNode> commentNodes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (CommentNode node : iterable) {
            commentNodes.add(node);
        }
        mCommentAdapter = new CommentAdapter(mContext, commentNodes);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mCommentAdapter);
    }

    private void showSnackBar(String message, boolean retry, final int retryCode) {
        mSnackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, message,
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        if (retry) {
            mSnackbar.setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch (retryCode) {
                        case RETRY_FIND_SUBMISSION:
                            findGameSubmission();
                            break;
                        case RETRY_FETCH_COMMENTS:
                            fetchComments();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        mSnackbar.show();
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void dismissSnackbar() {
        if (mSnackbar != null && mSnackbar.isShown()) {
            mSnackbar.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a Listing of Reddit Submissions, given a subreddit, a limit of submissions and a
     * sorting option.
     */
    private class FetchSubmissionListing extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Listing<Submission>> {
        private Context mContext;
        private String mSubreddit;
        private int mLimit;
        private Sorting mSorting;
        private SubmissionListingFetchListener mFetchListener;
        private AuthListener mAuthListener;

        public FetchSubmissionListing(Context context, String subreddit, int limit, Sorting sorting,
                                      SubmissionListingFetchListener fetchListener,
                                      AuthListener authListener) {
            mContext = context;
            mSubreddit = subreddit;
            mLimit = limit;
            mSorting = sorting;
            mFetchListener = fetchListener;
            mAuthListener = authListener;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Listing<Submission> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RedditAuthentication redditAuthentication = RedditAuthentication.getInstance();
            if (redditAuthentication.getRedditClient().isAuthenticated()) {
                SubredditPaginator paginator = new SubredditPaginator(
                        redditAuthentication.getRedditClient(), mSubreddit);
                paginator.setLimit(mLimit);
                paginator.setSorting(mSorting);
                try {
                    return paginator.next(false /* forceNetwork */);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    if (MyDebug.LOG) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Reddit auth error on FetchSubmissionListing.");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                mFetchListener.onFailure("Failed to connect to Reddit");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Listing<Submission> submissions) {
            if (submissions != null) {
                mFetchListener.onSuccess(submissions);
            } else {
                if (!RedditAuthentication.getInstance().getRedditClient().isAuthenticated()) {
                    // Attempt to authenticate once.
                    RedditAuthentication.getInstance().authenticate(mContext, mAuthListener);
                }
                mFetchListener.onFailure("Failed to connect to Reddit");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a "full" Reddit submission given a Reddit submisisonId. A "full" submission is one
     * that also contains its comment tree.
     * The sorting of the thread is determined by mThreadType (Live game or post game).
     */
    private class FetchFullSubmission extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Submission> {
        private Context mContext;
        private String mThreadId;
        private FullSubmissionFetchListener mFetchListener;
        private AuthListener mAuthListener;

        public FetchFullSubmission(Context context, String threadId,
                                   FullSubmissionFetchListener fetchListener,
                                   AuthListener authListener) {
            mContext = context;
            mThreadId = threadId;
            mFetchListener = fetchListener;
            mAuthListener = authListener;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Submission doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if (mThreadId == null) {
                return null;
            }
            SubmissionRequest.Builder builder = new SubmissionRequest.Builder(mThreadId);
            switch (mThreadType) {
                case LIVE_GAME_THREAD:
                    builder.sort(CommentSort.NEW);
                    break;
                case POST_GAME_THREAD:
                    builder.sort(CommentSort.TOP);
                    break;
                default:
                    builder.sort(CommentSort.TOP);
                    break;
            }
            SubmissionRequest submissionRequest = builder.build();
            try {
                return RedditAuthentication.getInstance()
                        .getRedditClient().getSubmission(submissionRequest);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (MyDebug.LOG) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Could not load submission in FetchFullSubmission.");
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Submission submission) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (submission != null) {
                mFetchListener.onSuccess(submission);
                mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                if (!RedditAuthentication.getInstance().getRedditClient().isAuthenticated()) {
                    // Attempt to re-authenticate once.
                    RedditAuthentication.getInstance().authenticate(mContext, mAuthListener);
                }
                mFetchListener.onFailure("Failed to connect to Reddit");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to get rid of this??

Screenshots of errors
:
[image: Error1]
[image: error2]

[image: CommnetThread1]

Comment: which is the line pointed to in the code?

Comment: I've edited the question, included screenshots

Answer (score 2):

You have implemented Butterknife in your library project. Butterknife doesnot work for library project.For more details you can follow this link
https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/45

Comment: Butterknife works in library . But u need to use R2.id.xxx instead of R.id.xxx

u need to add 
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

Comment: @MujeebRahamanT Still I am getting the same error after applying both plugins apply plugin: 'com.android.library' apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife. Could you please help me

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out on this [github issue](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/45#issuecomment-250088860), it can work by using R2.id instead of R.id when we are using Butterknife in library project.